# Selecting Voltage Divider Resistor and OpAmp For Temp Sensing With NTC Thermistor

Tags: temperature, thermistor

I've been doing some reading on here about measuring temperature with NTC thermistors and using the Steinhart-Hart Equation.

However I am still a bit confused about the selection of a resistor to put in a voltage divider with the thermistor. Should I select a resistor value that is the same as the thermistor's resistance at the centre of my range of interest (200F) to maximise the sensitivity?

Also do I need an opamp or inamp to remove any noise common to both thermistor leads as the thermistor probe will be in an espresso machine boiler, so I expect some mains and switching noise ?

If I use a precision voltage reference for the thermistor, my current understanding is that I must use that same voltage for the ADC, is this correct?

Comment: Are you sure a thermistor is the proper choice for measuring 200 C? Can you provide a data sheet?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast 200°F ~= 93°C. Not so bad.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Oops. Damn, I hate it when that happens.

Comment: There is an easy way to calculate the resistor value [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/498057/115047)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should use the mid-range-interest resistance. The exception might be if you were willing to give up some actual performance to make the temperature display look better at room temperature, with a low-resolution ADC.

Noise can be mitigated with a simple RC filter - temperature is a slow variable.

Reference voltage is preferably the same as the ADC but really a thermistor typically changes around -5%/degree C so any "reasonably stable" reference will give you acceptable performance for your particular application.

Comment: What would be a reasonable time constant for a low pass filter for a thermistor in a boiler?
I was planning on taking say 10 measurements (per second?), rejecting the outliers (?) and averaging the rest of the values to improve the resolution.
I've read in these forums that a moving average is also a type of low pass filter. If thats the case would it be sufficient to just use a 10uF electrolytic and a 0.1uF (ceramic?) in parallel to remove any non DC from the signal?

Comment: Time constant maybe 0.1~1 second. The commercial cappuccino machine I designed the controls for used a flash boiler so it used thermocouples and ran much hotter. I think there was a regulatory (safety) reason. If you have an input that can work with, say, 100K you can add some series resistance and then a capacitor such as a 1uF-10uF ceramic to ground.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand your statement "If you have an input that can work with, say, 100K you can add some series resistance"
Could you explain further please?

Comment: Whatever you are connecting the thermistor + resistor to will allow some maximum source resistance before the error gets unacceptable. If that number is low you probably can't add much resistance in series so the cap has to be large value. An op-amp buffer would easily allow 100K or more depending on the type so you can avoid using an electrolytic cap.

Comment: Should I be placing the RC low pass filter before or after the op-amp buffer? 
Also, the resistance of my thermistor at the temperature of interest (200F) is about 835 ohms. If I were to use an 835 ohm resistor in the divider, would that value be too low and cause self heating errors, considering that the probe would be inserted into a sealed vessel full of water. Or would any self heating be inconsequential considering the far greater thermal mass of the water (approx 2 litres) ?

Comment: Before the buffer. With a 5V supply the dissipation will be 7.4mW. Thermal mass is not so important, thermal impedance is. This might cause a few degrees F offset or more depending on the construction (see the datasheet for the probe or measure it). You can use a higher resistance thermistor- I would try to keep the resistance in the 5-10K range at the operating temperature, assuming a buffer.

Comment: Thank you. I've found a thermistor that has a resistance of 80.7K ohms at my temperature of interest. Can you tell me whether I would be better off using an instrumentation amplifier rather than an opamp as the unity gain buffer?

Comment: I see no advantage to an instrumentation amplifier in this application.

Comment: Might I need, instead of a unity gain op-amp, an op-amp set up with enough gain to fill the "window" of the total range I expect to see?  Or should I just use a reference voltage on the ADC for the maximum voltage that will be produced by the voltage divider ?

Comment: Thermistors are so nonlinear there (usually) isn't much to be gained by adding.. gain. Resolution is seldom your biggest problem with thermistors anyway. Just use the ADC reference for your thermistor + resistor and pick the series resistor optimally.

Comment: And just to be clear, I should be using an op-amp set up as a unity gain differential amplifier, correct?

Comment: Just a unity gain voltage follower.

Comment: Would something like a 741 op-amp be sufficient, or should I be looking for some specific characteristics in a op-amp?

Comment: Rail-to-rail input and output (RRIO) would be easiest to deal with. Probably Microchip has some appropriate ones.

Comment: I'm now using a RC filter with a 100K resistor and a 1uF capacitor giving a time constant of 0.1 seconds, then a voltage follower using a MCP6001 op-amp. I'm getting nice stable results. Thank you for your help @SpehroPefhany

Comment: I need to lengthen the thermistor leads, would a shielded twisted pair be the way to go?